# Magento count pagination sizes

Tags: pagination

Is there any way to count how many pages there is in pagination?
I'm not talking about Collection count, but something like pagination count maybe?

Comment: What page, what template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pagination is linked to a collection. To get the total number of pages use this:

```
$collection->getLastPageNumber();
```

If you have a pagination block in your page you can get the last page number like this:

```
$block->getLastPageNum();
```

Comment: I know magento-stackexchange want me to avoid thanks, but i say it anyway, thank you - it was exactly what i needed :)